# Is the Antequera-Granada high speed line open after 2019-12-15?

Tags: trains, spain, event-based-effects

The Antequera-Granada high speed line [opened 2019-06-26](https://www.railwaygazette.com/europe/granada-joins-the-ave-network/48776.article).  When I search for tickets on the [RENFE website](http://www.renfe.com/), I find tickets up to and including 2019-12-15 for trains Granada-Madrid and Granada-Barcelona, but none after that (only MD rail replacement for the old line).  I'm aware that RENFE are often very late in opening bookings after the December timetable change, but other AVE tickets such as Madrid-Barcelona and Madrid-Málaga are available for sale and have been for more than a week, so it appears to be something about the new line to Granada.

Is the high speed line Antequera-Granada still open after 2019-12-15 or is it closed?

Comment: Renfe's website is absolutely horrible (a satyrical webpage even has [a tag for it](https://www.elmundotoday.com/tag/web-de-renfe/)), so info is quite difficult to find. In any case, it seems to be a non-issue in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. I contacted privately the Renfe official account in Twitter ([@Renfe](https://twitter.com/Renfe)) and they replied:

> Los billetes Madrid-Granada y Barcelona-Granada, a partir del 15 de diciembre, se pondrán a la venta en los próximos días.

That is:

> Madrid-Granada and Barcelona-Granada tickets, from December 15, will be for sale in the upcoming days.

Note by the way that you can also buy a Madrid - Antequera AVE ticket and then have the Antequera - Granada ticket with a normal train (1h 30' time).

Comment: Thanks!  I also asked them on Twitter (on their public account, in my best Spanish) but they did not reply...

Comment: @gerrit they probably closed your question as a duplicate to my private message :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tickets became available 2019-11-21 (Thursday), 24 days in advance.  Thanks RENFE! `</s>`